# PyBrain: Why PyBrain NN does not learn to classify XOR?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, pybrain

I have the following code:

```python
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer 

ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)

ds.addSample((0, 0), (0,))
ds.addSample((0, 1), (1,))
ds.addSample((1, 0), (1,))
ds.addSample((1, 1), (0,))

net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True, hiddenclass=TanhLayer)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)

trainer.trainUntilConvergence()

print '0,0 : {0}'.format(net.activate([0, 0]))
print '0,1 : {0}'.format(net.activate([0, 1]))
print '1,0 : {0}'.format(net.activate([1, 0]))
print '1,1 : {0}'.format(net.activate([1, 1]))
```

The output I get converge always to something different that XOR. Example for an output I got:

```
0,0 : [ 1.33865922]
0,1 : [ 0.78127428]
1,0 : [ 0.8318278]
1,1 : [ 0.48067]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeeded solving it. Sharing the solution with you, so you can also use it:

Instead of using `trainer.trainUntilCovergence()`, I called `trainer.train()` K times (I used `K=1000`), and it worked

The change in my code:

```python
#trainer.trainUntilConvergence()
for i in xrange(1000):
    trainer.train()
```

The change in the output:

```
0,0 : [ 0.00347109]
0,1 : [ 0.99712772]
1,0 : [ 0.99725655]
1,1 : [ 0.00121727]
```

Note that when I used not enough iterations (e.g. 100), I got wrong outputs

Adding an important note of @dnth comment:

the reason trainUntilConvergence() dont work is because this method will divide your data into 75% training and 25% validation. Since you only have 4 sample data for the XOR problem, 1 data has been taken out to be the validation data and training is only done on the remaining 3 data. Therefore the solution found by the network is poor because the training data is incomplete for all case of the XOR

(Validation == Testing Set)

Comment: the reason trainUntilConvergence() dont work is because this method will divide your data into 75% training and 25% validation. Since you only have 4 sample data for the XOR problem, 1 data has been taken out to be the validation data and training is only done on the remaining 3 data. Therefore the solution found by the network is poor because the training data is incomplete for all case of the XOR

Comment: I didn't know this. What is the meaning of "validation"? Does it check whether it is well-trained (like when you have training set and testing set) ? Or "validation" is another step that is taken while training a neural network?

Comment: yeah, in this case validation is the testing set.. which is isolated out during the training and only used to test the network during training..